# My Loop Route in Google Transit is showing a 1 hour wait. Any help with my GTFS?

Tags: google-maps, google, general-transit-feed-specification, transit

I have a Loop Route that's showing a 1-hour wait time at the last/first stop.
[image: Google Query screenshot]

[Google Query example](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Whale+Park,+2500+Sawmill+Creek+Rd,+Sitka,+AK+99835/Sea+Mart+Quality+Foods,+9604,+Halibut+Point+Road,+Sitka,+AK/@57.0511328,-135.3349033,13z/am=t/data=!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x54045d43f3fa7923:0xfe1812478b480919!2m2!1d-135.2528009!2d57.0332625!1m5!1m1!1s0x5404664ee9295cc5:0x46205b2ec36703fe!2m2!1d-135.3667321!2d57.068146!3e3)

This is the last/first stop of my loop.

```
BLU,06:30:00,06:30:00,PRICE_ST,1,To Crescent Harbor
...
BLU,07:28:00,07:28:00,ARR_TRANSF,18,To Crescent Harbor
BLU,07:30:00,07:30:00,PRICE_ST,19,To Crescent Harbor
```

Have I misunderstood how to use the frequencies.txt? My understanding is that it adds 3600 seconds (1 hour) to the first stop's time and continues on from there.

```
trip_id,start_time,end_time,headway_secs,exact_times
BLU,06:30:00,19:30:00,3600,1
```

Or is there some issue with not enough time between the last stop and the first stop?

Comment: You have a transfers.txt that specifies two stops to transfer between, but you don't specify a min_transfer_time. While the spec suggests that transfer_type 1 should cover this case, it might be my guess to do so.

Comment: But it’s not a transfer, it’s the same vehicle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a block_id to my trips.txt. I didn't expect that to be the solution but today all my queries are resulting in trips with proper times, so I think that did it or somehow it fixed itself.

Edit: it now recognizes that it's the same vehicle.
[image: screenshot]